# Android 6.0 JSONStore init fail using Worklight 6.0.0.2 interim fix 201607021132

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using Worklight v6.0.0.2 interim fix 201607021132

But we get an error when we use WL.JSONStore.initCollection

[image: unsatisfiedLinkError]

This runtime exception is on Android 6.0.

Does WL.JSONStore is not support Android 6.0 in this interim fix?

Comment: So this works fine on Android devices with OS < 6?

Comment: works fine with android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade your project to MobileFirst 7.1 or MobileFirst 8.0.

This advice comes from [Idan Adar](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/01/11/support-plan-for-next-android-ios-mobile-os/) of IBM DevOps, who writes:

> …[IBM does] not plan to introduce support for the next Android and iOS releases in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 or earlier releases.
>
> For those of you who have Android or iOS apps developed using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 or earlier releases, and intend to have your app(s) running on the next Android or iOS version, you’ll have to upgrade to IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 or IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.